# Combining two loop into single with certain condition in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

With the following `x` vector I would like to create a vector of size `6` (grt1) with two conditions. For unique values of `x`, take the sub as below. For other positions of `grt1` like `3,5, and 6`, data from std normal.

```
h=c(1:6)
grt1=numeric(length(h)) #Null vector
x=c(1,2,2,4,4,4)
for (i in unique(x)){
  f=rep(x[x==i],3)
  grt1[i]=sum(f)
} ##Condition-1
 for( j in c(3,5,6))
 {
   grt1[j]=rnorm(1) 
 } ##Condition 2
```

The above code is working. But I want to make them a general statement by not specifying `c(3,5,6)` in the second condition.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `split`

```
v1 <- sapply(split(x, x), function(x) sum(rep(x, 3)))
grt1[grt1 == 0] <- rnorm(sum(grt1 == 0))
grt1
#[1]  3.0000000 12.0000000  0.3993774 36.0000000 -0.8149975 -1.2508617
```

---

If we need to use the OP's loop, get the index of elements that are 0 (because 'grt1' is initialized as a `numeric` vector of 0s) with `which`, loop over  it and assign those elements with `rnorm`

```
for(j in which(grt1 == 0))  grt1[j] <- rnorm(1)
grt1
#[1]  3.000000 12.000000 -0.765245 36.000000 -1.350172 -1.081518
```

NOTE: `rnorm` is `Vectorized`, so a `for` loop is not really needed here

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(x) %>% 
   group_by(x) %>%
   summarise(Sum = sum(rep(x, 3)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   complete(x = h) %>% 
   transmute(Sum = replace(Sum, is.na(Sum), rnorm(sum(is.na(Sum))))) %>%
   pull(Sum)
#[1]  3.0000000 12.0000000 -1.9279778 36.0000000  0.7900143 -0.2506099
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do it using any loop?

Comment: @Uddin I guess your question was to change the manual 3, 5, 6 right?  The updated code does that

Answer (score 0):

`which(duplicated(x))` would give you `c(3, 5, 6)`. Try :

```
inds <- which(duplicated(x))

for (i in unique(x)) {
  f=rep(x[x==i],3)
  grt1[i]=sum(f)
} 
for( j in inds){
  grt1[j]=rnorm(1) 
}
```